# Conditional Formatting duplicate entries - ignore certain text

Tags: excel, duplicates, conditional-formatting

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have a very basic example I have created. The idea is that a member of staff is allocated to a specific area. E.g. James in the Gym in the morning but on this example he is also in the classroom. This wouldn't be possible so I would like a warning to flag up.

When using the conditional formatting it doesn't work correctly. It will flag up words such as classroom or bathroom if there are multiple entries. It has to ignore these.

I have created a list with specific names that it should check but I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried splitting the information in the cells, so that teacher name goes in one cell, & area in another. That way you can assign the formatting to the teacher cells only, so that if the name occurs more than once in a period, it will flag up.

hope this helps.
Aron